# PRIMARY KEY auto-increments on INSERT IGNORE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Here's an entire insert: http://codebin.org/view/61969a27

Here's an example of that insert:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `listings`
(
    `feed_id` ,
     `source` ,
    `time` ,
    `country`,
    `state` ,
    `city` ,
    `zip`,
    `title` ,
    `url`
)
VALUES (
     '5050498326',
     'cl_web',
     '1433027144',
     'US',
     'AL',
     'Auburn',
     '36830',
     'Moms Helping Moms Work From Home!',
     'http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/5050498326.html'
 ), (
     '5050537388',
     'cl_web',
     '1433026553',
     'US',
     'AL',
     'Auburn',
     '36830',
     'Moms Helping Moms Work From Home!',
     'http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/5050537388.html'
);
```

What I'm finding is that auto_increment is increasing on 'failed' inserts, or rather inserts that are ignored.

I have a list of values and a lot of the time (most of the time) I already have those in the database.

Is there another way to write this query so that auto_increment does not increase? Furthermore, is there a better more optimal way to write this kind of query? I know you can do inserts on selects, but I am in no way familiar enough with SQL.

Comment: Auto increment should be NOT NULL and PRIMARY KEY. ie The value cannot be null. You can pass the auto increment column value which overrides the increment value. Either you remove these attributes for not to increment. With these attributes you can't.

Comment: id (which I'm not passing) is auto_increment, not null, and PRIMARY KEY. There is also a UNIQUE INDEX for feed_id and source.

Comment: Its not possible to ignore man..

Comment: Whats your table schema post it too

Comment: Side Note: There may be a way you could turn Identity Insert on and off on PK NOT NULL columns.  (I know you can in MSSQL, just not sure about MYSQL)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine there are two transactions.  The first transaction aborts after they both request a new auto-increment value.  Since the second transaction must have received a higher auto-increment number, and the first transaction did not use its assigned number, there is now be a gap.  It is theoretically impossible to guarantee gapless auto-increment columns.

You can reduce the gaps by using a `where` clause to filter out key violations. For example, this query only inserts a row if the PK is not taken:

```
insert  Table1
        (pk, col1)
select  1
,       'val1'
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Table1
        where   pk = 1
        )
```

This requires more SQL code than `insert ignore`, but should result in fewer auto-increment gaps.